# jQuery CLNDR: add div within date block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

I'm currently using the CLNDR plugin: http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/ a great little jQuery plugin for producing calendars. Ideally I'm looking to use the calendar as an events calendar, i.e. if you add an event to a specific date, it will add the relevant info to that date block. 
I currently have this jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/32EEF/ 
Where by default, the events in array are styled with a different background color. Ideally what I want to add a div within the `.day` div that contains an event, containing the event title, info etc etc. Nothing too fancy, just something more than changing the background color. Is this at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  // here's some magic to make sure the dates are happening this month.
  var thisMonth = moment().format('YYYY-MM');

  // Here's our events array. We could grab this via AJAX as well.
  var eventArray = [
    { date: thisMonth + "-24 07:52", title: "This is an event title", url: "http://google.com", time: "7:15PM" },
    { date: thisMonth + "-28", title: "the 28th, Part 1", url: "http://www.google.com" },
    { date: thisMonth + "-28", title: "the 28th, Part 2", arbitraryObject: 42 },
    { date: thisMonth + "-16", title: "Another title", anotherObject: "clndr exposes whatever is in your event object" }
  ];

  var clndr2 = $('.cal2').clndr({
    template: $('#template-calendar').html(),
    events: eventArray,
    startWithMonth: moment().add('month', 0),
    clickEvents: {
      click: function(target) {
        console.log(target);
      }
    }
  });

  // bind both clndrs to the left and right arrow keys
  $(document).keydown( function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
      // left arrow
      clndr1.back();
      clndr2.back();
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
      // right arrow
      clndr1.forward();
      clndr2.forward();
    }
  });

});
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">

      <h3></h3>

    <div class="cal2">
      <script type="text/template" id="template-calendar">
        <div class="clndr-controls">
          <div class="clndr-previous-button">&lsaquo;</div>
          <div class="month"><%= month %></div>
          <div class="clndr-next-button">&rsaquo;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clndr-grid">
          <div class="days-of-the-week">
            <% _.each(daysOfTheWeek, function(day) { %>
              <div class="header-day"><%= day %></div>
            <% }); %>
            <div class="days">
              <% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
                <div class="<%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>"><%= day.day %></div>
              <% }); %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </script>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still would add the div manually so I will keep the other answer and make a new. Looking at the plugin you can always add the div to all days and then adjust the style so that the events looks a bit different.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/32EEF/5/

What I did was adjust the template to add a div (with a custom class like container):

```
<% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
    <div class="<%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>"><div class="container"><%= day.day %></div></div>
<% }); %>
```

Then add some styles to events:

```
.day .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.day.event .container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin:25%;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

That way you can add elements inside the events and have them look more different than just color.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know CLNDR but you could do it manually.
Since every day in the calendar gets a unique id you can use that to insert your events.
like:

```
$("#calendar-day-2013-11-16").insert($("<div/>").html("Inner event div"));
```

So for each event in your array check the date and use $("calendar-day-") (replaceing  with the date of the event).

But I not know the plugin. Might be more functionality that you are missingm, then you might instead want to do a loop over all $(".event"). Match the date (that you get from the id) and check your array for what you need to place in that div.

Unless there is a method in CLNDR that handles custom content for the calendar.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Yes, the plugin is only about a month old, so there's limited documentation / demos for it. Ideally, as the site will be content managed I'd need a solution that takes every event in the array and adds a div to the relevant date block, instead of me having to do it manually...if possible